# How to install/setup Allure Reporting for robot framework?

Tags: python, report, robotframework

I have followed the instructions on git hub and have installed/ran the following commands:

```
pip install allure-robotframework
pip install robotframework-allure
```

and in my robot script I have the following statement

```
Library AllureReportingLibrary
```

I am running the following command in cmd line:

```
robot --listener allure_robotframework ./my_robot_test
```

but it says it cannot find option listner.

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please include the actual error message?

Answer (score 3):

The listener parameter should be defined without spaces. 
In the case when you have spaces it should be defined inside quotes `' '`:

```
robot --listener 'allure_robotframework;./results/allure'
```

Also:

- if you do `pip install allure-robotframework`, then you don't need to install also `robotframework-allure`.
- `Library AllureReportingLibrary` is not necessary to point in your robot file.
- Once the report is generated you need to execute the following command `allure serve ./results/allure`, then you will be redirected to the report page on your browser.

For more info: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_report_generation

Comment: Still not working. Still comes up with the error: listener not recognized.

Comment: I have the following command: robot --listener 'allure_robotframework;./verification.robot'

Comment: Okay, I've figured it out: **Allure** needs your `output.xml` file, so as a 2nd parameter there should be pointed the path to your results, e.g. `--listener 'allure_robotframework;./results/allure'`.

Comment: @Konstantin V, Can you please explain it further. It is generating a lot of .html files with single line of text but not the actual allure report

Comment: @Anuj Teotia, once the report is generated you need to execute the following command `allure serve ./results/allure`, then you will be redirected to the report page on your browser.
For more info: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_report_generation

Comment: @Anuj Teotia, good to know! You can vote for my answer to help others to find the solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Konstantin solution, but it generate me only a lot of .html files and couple of .json files. In each html file there is a single line of text with robot framework, e.g. keyword name or what variable was returned

```
robot --listener 'allure_robotframework;./results' ./Tests
```

Comment: Is this feedback or a new question? (Late Answer Review).

Comment: @Konstantin V you might wanto to help OP of the answer here...? Lee flee of the stage I guess.

Comment: I followed steps provided here: https://pypi.org/project/allure-robotframework/

Comment: Please find my answer in another thread below my solution posted on Sep 17 '19 at 10:42

Answer (score 0):

the way is , first install the package

> *allure-robotframework or robotframework-allure*.

then run the command

> `robot --listener allure_robotframework ./'path to your robot file'`

upon completion of test and generation of data(.html and .json files) use

> `allure serve ./'path to data generated(folder containing json, html files)'`.

this will open the browser and you will be able to see the report.

if it is showing that 'allure' keyword is not recognized , then install **allure-commandline** in your device, add the path to its batch file which is inside the bin folder to the system environment variables , restart your Pycharm and then it will work fine.
I did not face the 'listener not recognized' problem using this command-

> `robot --listener allure_robotframework ./'path to your robot file'`

for any further questions , do comment and I will try to answer with the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

there should be no semicolon. It should be like

```
robot --listener allure_robotframework ./tests
```